# Flutter Issue: No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context

Tags: flutter

> Performing hot restart... Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86
> arm... Restarted application in 1,910ms.
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> assertion was thrown building MyApp(state: _MyAppState#6de06):
> MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a
> MediaQuery.
>
> No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that
> was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you do not have
> a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a
> MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a
> widget above those widgets. The context used was: Scaffold   dirty
> state: ScaffoldState#edc68(lifecycle state: initialized, tickers:
> tracking 2 tickers) The relevant error-causing widget was:    MyApp
> file:///S:/Businesses/Furniture/APP/movonpf/lib/main.dart:10:10 When
> the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:819:5)
> #1      ScaffoldState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:2207:50)
> #2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4786:12)
> #3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) ...     Normal
> element mounting (9 frames) ...
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> assertion was thrown building MyApp(state: _MyAppState#6de06):
> MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a
> MediaQuery.
>
> No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that
> was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you do not have
> a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a
> MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a
> widget above those widgets. The context used was: Scaffold   dirty
> state: ScaffoldState#b5bf9(lifecycle state: initialized, tickers:
> tracking 2 tickers) The relevant error-causing widget was:    MyApp
> file:///S:/Businesses/Furniture/APP/movonpf/lib/main.dart:10:10 When
> the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:819:5)
> #1      ScaffoldState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:2207:50)
> #2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4786:12)
> #3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
> #4      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) ...
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a
> MediaQuery. The relevant error-causing widget was:    MyApp
> file:///S:/Businesses/Furniture/APP/movonpf/lib/main.dart:10:10

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movonpf/views/login_page.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: SplashScreen(
            seconds: 1,
               image: Image.asset('assets/movonSplash.gif'),
              photoSize: 200.0,
              loaderColor: Colors.white,
              navigateAfterSeconds: LoginScreen(),
    ))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `Scaffold` widget with a `MaterialApp` to provide the MediaQuery.